# Manejo de una petición en a una base de datos (SQL) que no devuelve nada en PHP (CODEIGNITER)

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Estoy creando una función que recibe un nombre de una categoría de un super (Frescos, Lácteos, etc.) y tiene que buscar en la BD por el nombre para devolver el ID de la categoría, hasta aquí bien. El caso es que quiero que si al buscar el nombre de la categoría, no la encuentra en la BD, me devuelva -1. Para eso tengo siguiente código:

```
public function verIDCategoria($name)
{
    $query = "select id from categoria where nombre='$name'";
    $catnom = $this->db->query($query);
    if (!$catnom){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return $catnom->row()->id;
    }
}
```

Si añado print_r($catnom); , me devuelve esto:

> CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $ [client_version] => 50012 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 1 [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.7.26 [server_version] => 50726 [stat] => Uptime: 40850 Threads: 1 Questions: 1975 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 201 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 194 Queries per second avg: 0.048 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 294 [warning_count] => 0 ) [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => )

Esta es la función que dado el nombre de la categoría te devuelve su ID. Pero no se como manejarlo cuando no hay nada en el resultado de la petición para que devuelva -1. Puesto que al pasar esto, me da el error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

```
EDIT
```

Este el la parte del controlador que llama a las funciones:

```
public function verificarProducto()
{
      $prueba = $this->mproducto->verCategoriasEx($this->input->post('categoria'));
      $file = fopen("nprod.txt", "a");
      fwrite($file, "0. ID devuelto: " . $prueba . PHP_EOL);
      fclose($file);
      //AQUI ME DOY CUENTO DE QUE DEVUELVE -1 AUNQUE YA EXISTA EN LA BD
      if($this->mproducto->verCategoriasEx($this->input->post('categoria')) >= 0){
        $a = intval($this->mproducto->verCategoriasEx($this->input->post('categoria')));
        $file = fopen("nprod.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, "1. ID Cat if: " . $a . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($file);
      }else{
        $datos_cat = array(
          'nombre' => $this->input->post('categoria'),
          'descripcion' => "",
          'anuncio' => 0,
          'mostrar' => 1
        );

        $a = $this->mproducto->insertaCategoria($datos_cat);
        $file = fopen("nprod.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, "2. ID Cat else: " . $a . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($file);
      }
}
```

Y estas son las dos funciones llamadas (he cambiado algunos nombres de variables):

```
public function verCategoriasEx($nombre)
{
    $file = fopen("nprod.txt", "a");
    fwrite($file, "El nombre de la categoría es " . $nombre . PHP_EOL);
    $query = "select id from categoria where nombre='" . $nombre . "' LIMIT 1";
    fwrite($file, "La query es: " . $query . PHP_EOL);
    $catnom = $this->db->query($query, array($nombre));
    $resultado = $catnom->row();
    $final = $resultado->id;
    fwrite($file, "resultado es: " . $final); 
    fclose($file);
    if ($catnom->num_rows){
        return $catnom->row()->id;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}

public function insertaCategoria($cat)
{
    $this->db->insert('categoria', $cat);

    $nombre = $cat['nombre'];
    $query = "select id from categoria where nombre='$nombre'";
    $catnom = $this->db->query($query);
    return $catnom->row()->id;
}
```

El resultado del volcado en el archivo nprod.txt es:

```
2. ID Cat else: 57
El nombre de la categoría es CategoriaNueva
La query es: select id from categoria where nombre='CategoriaNueva' LIMIT 1
resultado es: 570. ID devuelto: -1
El nombre de la categoría es CategoriaNueva
La query es: select id from categoria where nombre='CategoriaNueva' LIMIT 1
resultado es: 572. ID Cat else: 57
```

Por lo que estoy viendo que el paso 0 y 1 de la parte del controlador ni se está ejecutando, no sé por qué.

```
FIN EDIT
```

Comment: ¿Usas PDO o mysqli?

Comment: Estoy usando mysql

Comment: Ya, pero ¿qué API para la conexión, `mysqli` o PDO?

Comment: Perdón, no he puesto la i, es mysqli jajaja

Comment: El error te dice que el objeto row no está definido, y por tanto no puedes acceder a una propiedad id. Puedes probar a imprimir con print_r($catnom) su contenido para ver qué te devuelve la BBDD?

Comment: Acabo de añadir a la pregunta el resultado de print_r($catnom); ;)
Por otro lado, es imposible que row no esté definido, porque en caso de que la categoría sí exista, no me da ningún error.

Comment: Pues precisamente es lo que pasa, que no existe el resultado de llamar la método row(). Por eso te da el error de intentar acceder a una propiedad (id) del objeto null (que es lo que te está devolviendo el método row). Puedes comprobarlo añadiendo print_r($catnom->row())

Comment: Si estabas usando CodeIgniter era lo primero que tenías que haber mencionado.

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT: Solución para CodeIgniter

El código que tenías debería funcionar con CodeIgniter. No obstante, se puede mejorar usando una consulta preparada.

Si no funciona es porque la búsqueda con el criterio `$name` no se cumple. En ese caso debes revisar esa variable y verificar que realmente existen datos con ese criterio.

En el contexto donde pasas `$name`, o en esta función, deberías validar también que  `$name` no está vacío o nulo.

```
public function verIDCategoria($name)
{
    $query = "select id from categoria where nombre=? LIMIT 1";
    $catnom = $this->db->query($query,array($name));
    #Verificar si la consulta retorna filas   
    if ($catnom->num_rows) 
    { 
        #Obtenemos la fila con el método row() y retornamos el id
        return $catnom->row()->id;
    } else {
        #No hay datos, retornamos -1
        return -1;
    }
}
```

---

### Solución válida para mysqli puro

Cuando ejecutas `query` lo que obtienes es un puntero hacia los datos. Tienes luego que usar alguno de los métodos de lectura para obtener los datos. En `mysqli` son los métodos `fetch_` que aparecen en el Manual, son varios que te devuelven los datos organizados de una forma o de otra.

Puedes hacerlo así, he explicado todo en comentarios del código:

```
public function verIDCategoria($name)
{
    $query = "select id from categoria where nombre='$name' LIMIT 1";
    $catnom = $this->db->query($query);
    #Verificar si no hay error en la consulta y si hay filas    
    if (($catnom) && ($catnom->num_rows !== 0)) 
    { 
        #Hay que usar un método fetch para leer los datos
        $row = $catnom->fetch_assoc();
        #Retornamos el id
        return $row["id"];
    } else {
        #No hay datos, retornamos -1
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Si no entiendes algo, puedes preguntar en el área de comentarios.

Comment: Lo he entendido perfectamente!! Muchas gracias, funciona genial ;)

Comment: Acabo de publicar una nueva respuesta a esta pregunta con un error que estoy teniendo al seguir esta solución ;)

Comment: @Alfred revisa la solución editada. Tu código estaba bien, aunque conviene que apliques consultas preparadas (lo he hecho en la edición para CodeIgniter). Si te arroja cero filas será debido a que el critero con `$name` no se cumple.  Si no lo estás haciendo, debes validar que `$name` no sea nulo o vacío.

Comment: La variable $name funciona bien, he hecho un volcado de la variable a un archivo antes de ejecutar la consulta y me saca el nombre de la variable que le he pasado. Pero aun existiendo en la BD, me devuelve -1. Es muuuuy extraño :(

Comment: @Alfred haz un `var_dump($name)` para verificar bien la variable, que no tenga espacios en blanco por ejemplo. Y luego haz un `SELECT` escrito a mano en la base de datos directamente y dime si arroja filas.

Comment: He verificado la variable y todo genial, no me ha dado ningún problema si la escribo directamente en la BD, me devuelve la fila correspondiente. Voy a editar de nuevo la pregunta para añadir las dos funciones que son llamadas desde el controlador principal y la parte del controlador que llama a estas dos funciones, a ver si así podemos encontrarlo.. :S

Comment: Ya está, acabo de publicar lo nuevo en la pregunta.